# SQL active users by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know the number of active users by month, I use SQL Server 2017.

I have an AuditLog table like:

```
- UserID: int
- DateTime: datetime
- AuditType: int

UserID  DateTime     AuditType
------------------------------
1       2022-01-01   1
1       2022-01-15   4
1       2022-02-20   3
2       2022-01-10   8
2       2022-03-10   1
3       2022-03-20   1
```

If someone has at least one entry in a given month then he/she is treated as active.
I would like to have a result like:

```
Date     Count
2022-01  2
2022-02  1
2022-03  2
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: What did you try, and why did that fail?  (stackoverflow is not a code writing service...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine the function `Month(datetime)` in the `GROUP BY` with the Count function `SELECT COUNT(UserID)`

Comment: It was simple, I don't know what was my problem. Thank you!

SELECT
 (YEAR(DateTime) * 100) + MONTH(DateTime) as Month,
 COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) as Count
FROM
 Audit 
--WHERE
-- DateTime>='2022-01-01'
GROUP BY
 (YEAR(DateTime) * 100) + MONTH(DateTime)
ORDER BY
 (YEAR(DateTime) * 100) + MONTH(DateTime)

Comment: use distinct in count

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CAST(YEAR(C.DATE)AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(C.DATE)AS CHAR(2)))YEAR_MONTH,COUNT(C.USER_ID)CNTT
FROM AUDITLOG AS C
GROUP BY (CAST(YEAR(C.DATE)AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(C.DATE)AS CHAR(2)))
ORDER BY (CAST(YEAR(C.DATE)AS CHAR(4))+'-'+CAST(MONTH(C.DATE)AS CHAR(2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solutions,

```
Select [Date],count(1) as Count From (
select Cast(cast(d.DateTime as date) as varchar(7)) as [Date],UserId 
from AuditLog d 
Group by Cast(cast(d.DateTime as date) as varchar(7)),UserId
) as q1 Group by [Date]
Order by 1
```

Hope, it will works.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP DATE (Year and Month) either combine or separate and count distinct userId

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), [DateTime], 126)[Date], COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)[Count] 
FROM AuditLog
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), [DateTime], 126)
```